# Five ways to say a sentence for giving emphasize

Tags: sentence-usage

1. I walk five miles to bloody school every day.
2. I walk five miles to damn school every day.
3. I go on Shank's pony five miles to school every day.
4. I trudge five miles to school every day.
5. I slog five miles to school every day.

Do the sentences stated above make any sense? Do you think that the sentences stated above are right? Please tell the differences in meaning of them.

Answer (score 2):

What the heck is with 3? Must not be anywhere near my region. I mean, I wouldn't use "bloody" either, but that's just because I'm not a Brit, I've never even heard of Shank's pony.

Anyway, 1 and 2 could use some retargeting. You seem to mean that the length of the walk is making you upset. I would place the emphasis here:

> I walk five **damn** miles to school every day.

You could ramp it up from kinda pissed to sheer outrage by adding more:

> I walk five damn miles to this stupid fucking school every single fucking day.

"This" is used as a diminutive, having to denote which school you mean makes it feel less important. It also targets the insults more specifically at a certain school than schools in general, giving them more force.

As for your examples more specifically, 4 and 5 merely emphasize that it's an annoyance, 1 and 2 are about your current emotions relating to the subject. The sentences are pretty interchangeable inside the pairs, except "bloody" is going to sound a little strange to an American English speaker.

Comment: Shanks's pony is British slang for walking, although it's not commonly used.